# C# how to get possible values for xml node / attribute when validating

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, xml-validation

I'am validate XML against XSD schema by XDocument.Validate()/XElement.Validate() method (or by XmlDocument.Validate()) and have the following error messages:

> The 'gender' attribute is invalid - The value 'X' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
>
> The 'GTX' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'requiredString' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value.
>
> The 'amount' attribute is invalid - The value '999' is invalid according to its datatype 'requiredId' - The actual value is less than the MaxInclusive value.

How I can get the (Max/Min)Inclusive/Exclusive/Length, (Min/Max)Occurs, list of possible values for node/attribute from XSD for the current issue?

For example with a list of possible elements (tags) all ok in error message:

> The element 'foo' has invalid child element 'baz'. List of possible elements expected: 'bar, par'

I've read about XmlSchemaValidator object, but I don't want to deserialize XML in any model because the structure can be changed and for XSD too.

Can someone help me with this? Or maybe I can use XmlSchemaValidator somehow differently?
Maybe somebody can give a link to example how validate XML w/o binding to the document structure?

Comment: Open the xsd file.  It is text and has all the acceptable values.  The xsd may reference URL and going to the URL page there are documents with the acceptable values.

Comment: jdweng XSD doesn't has any reference (w/o namespace)
Yes, I agree with you that it is just a text, but what if there will 2 elements with same name in diff places and with diff possible values for example ?

Comment: You have to look at the entire structure, not just the local name.  It is not correct when look at a person say the color is blue without saying if it is skin, hair, or eyes.

Comment: @jdweng I'am not sure that I understand you correctly, but I can't reference to entire structure, because it can change in future. 
Maybe you can give me link to some example ?

Comment: I just saying for debugging the discrepancies you can manually look at the xsd to find the root cause of the outages.  When looking you just can't look at the tag name you also have to look at the parents.